# WP Custom post type multilingual content with Polylang

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I have an issue that i do not now how to solve.

I have a wordpress page that is multilingual thanks to Polylang plugin. Everything works great except custom post type from [themify's Post Type Builder](https://themify.me/post-type-builder).

Post created with this custom post type loads content for Base language, but whenever I change the language it stops working. It does not load content and loads only the header and the footer sections.

this is the output:

Any Ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should add your custom post types in polylang setting and refresh the setting

Comment: It's already on polylang settings and I have select this Custom Type to be translated with polylang.

Comment: in your theme, do you have if lang equal to any thing for showing post?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question, this problem is only in Custom Post Types, Posts and Pages are working perfect in both languages.

Comment: i said, are you put conditions for show post of any language in your theme?

Comment: I have the posts in both languages.

Answer (score 0):

resolved by changing the permalinks settings on Polylang.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Option To update custom type post language]

[image: Select Where you want to add support]

Langulages>Settings>Custom post types and Taxonomies>checkbox